How to generate token when login with abpio
I want to know that how can we generate JWT token in abpio when login.
In response header it return
cache-control: no-cache,no-store
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon,01 Apr 2024 12:30:51 GMT
expires: Thu,01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Kestrel
x-correlation-id: ced12d9fa69e4e4db10665ae9a3ee9bf
I had explore the documentation but it doesn't work.


Write a function to get JWT token
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
public class AccountAppService : ApplicationService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AccountAppService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<string> LoginAsync(LoginRequest input)
    {
        var user = AuthenticateUser(input);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        return GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
    }

    private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel userInfo)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["App:Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
//here "App:Jwt:Issuer" is your private string appsetting.json and environment variable (.env) file
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_configuration["App:Jwt:Issuer"],
          _configuration["App:Jwt:Issuer"],
          null,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
          signingCredentials: credentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

    private UserModel AuthenticateUser(LoginRequest login)
    {
        // For demo purposes, use hardcoded credentials. Replace this with your user validation logic.
        if (login.Username == "Jignesh" && login.Password == "password")
        {
            return new UserModel { Username = "Jignesh Trivedi", EmailAddress = "test.btest@gmail.com" };
        }

        return null;
    }
}


Create a Need Modal, service, and controller to use it

Update ConfigureServices in {{App}}Module.cs to validate your jwt token for protected endpoint
{
    context.services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = configuration["App:Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = configuration["App:Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["App:Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
} 



Add UseAuthetication and UseAuthorization to allow authentication  and authentication while request


public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)

    {   var app = context.GetApplicationBuilder();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();  
    } 

Ask more questions if you need more help.
